# 3D Sandbox game: Detecting when a block is no longer attached to the ground

Tags: physics

I've been playing "Ace of Spades" recently, mostly because my son likes that. They have a feature that my son calls "gravity", but I don't know the official name. Anyway, the effect of "gravity" is that if you have a tower, and you remove the last block at the bottom, the game engine detects that the rest of the tower is not connected to the game world/ground anymore, and makes the tower fall apart.

My question is: how do you *quickly* detect that a part of the game world is not connected anymore (and which part)?

While "Ace of Spades" levels are fixed-size, an algorithm that also works for "infinite worlds" would be preferred. If that kind of problem has a specific name, I'd like to know that as well, since it helps when looking for possible implementations ...

I think this is somehow similar to how a *garbage collector* works: when there is no "path" from the ground to a block, then it is disconnected (garbage).

Comment: Also: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50953/determining-if-removal-of-a-voxel-will-break-up-a-group?lq=1

Comment: OK, that other question is basically the same thing. I'm not quite sure if the accepted solution fits my need, as in my case the world is infinite, but it still does make my question a duplicate.