# How does collapsable structures in a voxel based game like Ace of Spades/Build and Shoot work?

Tags: python, voxels, panda3d

I know that once all the cubes that are connected are destroyed, the unconnected blocks collapse. How do you find out the unconnected blocks?

edit 1: How would you determine the collapsible object if it spans multiple chunks?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50891/algorithm-to-see-if-two-voxels-are-interconnected and related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50953/determining-if-removal-of-a-voxel-will-break-up-a-group

Comment: I think it is a duplicate...thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that each voxel object contains a reference to its adjacent voxels. When a voxel is changed it calls some kind of update function on each of those references.